# How to run a query in PL/SQL with Serializable transaction isolation

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, transaction, isolation-level, plsql-developer

I want to run this SQL in Oracle 11g:

```
declare a number;
  begin 
  select count(*) into a  from item w where w.Item_num='MOH601' ; 
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
  end ;
```

How to run this query with isolation Serializable? As I have learnt before, Oracle will lock the rows with `w.Item_num='MOH601'` when using Serializable.

Comment: Please do not cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39363842/how-to-run-a-query-in-pl-sql-developer-with-serializable-transaction-isolation

Answer (score 5):

Alter the session:

```
declare a number;
  begin 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL SERIALIZABLE';
    select count(*) into a  from item w where w.Item_num='MOH601' ; 
    dbms_output.put_line(a);
  end ;
```

Comment: the equal sign is missing , but when i use it take :ORA-01453: SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction
ORA-06512: at line 4